# Will Flutter support Dynamic Delivery

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure

can this be done for apps created with Flutter? if yes how this can be done with flutter

Comment: create a github issue on flutter's repo

Comment: Dart offer that possibility, using deffered loading. But flutter doesn't support it.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18070 Please have a look on this .